# Google play voucher option displayed for in-app upgrade but not valid after all

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

I just wanted to buy the pro version of an Android app (Memrise). The Pro version is not a separate app but an in-app upgrade function.

So I chose my preferred subscription, and the usual Play Store dialogue popped up and asked me to choose a payment option. Since I got a 50 Euro voucher I chose the option "Gutschein einlösen" ("redeem a voucher" or something similar in English). So I typed in the code and my payment validations and the cash transferred to my account. But before I was able to complete the transaction the Google Play Store told me, that a voucher is not a valid option to pay the app upgrade.

So why was there the voucher option in the first place if it is not a valid option? I have no use for other apps/music and stuff except for that specific upgrade. Is there a way to get the upgrade / the money back anyway or are the 50 Euro just gone?

Comment: is there a more proper stack exchange category to ask that question?

Comment: Not very sure, maybe you can try [android.se]?

Comment: Yes. [android.se] or [webapps.se]